# dust sealed connectors for PCB to wire, and wire to wire

Tags: connector, automotive

I am working on a solar car, and I have been going back and forth on what connectors to use to seal out the dust, and keep the wires together during extreme vibrations. I am looking for wire to board, and board to board connections. I have looked at the molex MX150L connections, but the durability does not seem to be high (only 25 cycles). Does anyone know of another product that would meet the specifications with a higher durability, and the ability to cary low level logic connections.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have look into these suppliers: [TE connectivity (used to be AMP)](http://www.te.com/en/home.html), [Deutsch connectors](http://www.deutsch.net/deutsch-home.aspx), [Amphenol](http://www.amphenol.com), [Hypertronics](http://www.hypertronics.com).

Also, circular [MIL connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Military_connector_specifications) may be useful for you.  Many manufacturers make them.